# Unable to delete/edit record from pk

Tags: python-3.x, django

I've got a list of properties in a view and template. On the template I have an edit button and a delete button. Neither are working yet the same code from different projects work just fine. They don't throw any debug error, on the explorer or at the log level. It accepts the click/input, goes to the proper URL but remains on the "rei_properties" page.

I am running Django 3.1.6 framework...

view to see all records in "Property" model:

```
def rei_properties(request):
    props = Property.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'rei/rei_properties.html', {'props': props})
```

template w/ edit/delete links:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>City</th>
  <th>State</th>
  <th>Zipcode</th>
  <th colspan=2>Actions</th>
 </tr>
{% for prop in props %}
 <tr>
  <td>{{ prop.address }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ prop.city }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ prop.state }}</a></td>
  <td>{{ prop.zipcode }}</a></td>
  <td>
        <a href="{% url 'rei_properties' %}edit/{{ prop.pk }}/">Edit</a>
 </td>
 <td>
        <a href="{% url 'rei_properties' %}del/{{ prop.pk }}/" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>
 </td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

My urls:

```
    url(r'^rei_properties/', views.rei_properties, name='rei_properties'),
    url(r'^rei_properties/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]{1,10})/$', views.rei_properties_edit, name='rei_properties_edit'),
    url(r'^rei_properties/del/(?P<pk>[0-9]{1,10})/$', views.rei_properties_del, name='rei_properties_del'),
```

and finally my delete and edit views:

```
def rei_properties_edit(request, pk):
    prop = get_object_or_404(Property, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PropertyForm(request.POST, instance=prop)
        if form.is_valid():
            prop = form.save(commit=False)
            prop.save()
            return redirect('rei_properties')
    else:
        form = PropertyForm(instance=prop)
    return render(request, 'rei/rei_properties_edit.html', {'form': form})

def rei_properties_del(request, pk):
    Property.objects.get(pk=pk).delete()
    return redirect('rei_properties')
```

Answer (score 1):

change ,

```
<td>
        <a href="{% url 'rei_properties' %}edit/{{ prop.pk }}/">Edit</a>
 </td>

 <td>
        <a href="{% url 'rei_properties' %}del/{{ prop.pk }}/" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>
 </td>
```

to

```
<td>
        <a href="{% url 'rei_properties_edit' prop.pk %}">Edit</a>
 </td>
 <td>
        <a href="{% url 'rei_properties_del' prop.pk  %}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>
 </td>
```

The url's name attribute is used to directly link up the call from a template rather than making the url format...

**ADDED**
I would suggest you to name your app in the urls.py like ,

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

app_name = 'your_app_name'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home , name = "your_url_name"),
]
```

and from the templates you can reference the specific url of a specific app because there might be the same url name in different application... like ,

```
<td>
        <a href="{% url 'rei_properties' %}edit/{{ prop.pk }}/">Edit</a>
 </td>

 <td>
        <a href="{% url 'your_app_name:your_url_name' %}del/{{ prop.pk }}/" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')">Delete</a>
 </td>
```

Comment: One more problem is that OP has a pattern `^rei_properties/` this will also match the pattern `^rei_properties/edit/(?P<pk>[0-9]{1,10})/$` and the delete one because it doesn't end in a `$`, so the first view will be used for all 3 urls.

Comment: Deleting an object should be done through a POST request, or a DELETE request, not a GEt request.

Comment: It was because I didn't add `$` at the end of `^rei_properties/` url.